# how to implement beautifulsoup with a while loop and continuously detect data changes

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I am scraping a website, where I have a website link that I will scrape and has an update time of approximately 6-8 hours. If the data doesn't change then it remains the same. Basically, something which means I don't have to keep clicking run to see if the data has changed.

Besides that, I want to do a scrape by making the file into csv. here I attach my code in doing scrape on the website

```
import csv
import re
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = "https://www.ndbc.noaa.gov/station_page.php?station=56003"
request_headers = {
    "user-agent": ("Mozilla / 5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64)"
                   "AppleWebKit / 537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko)"
                   "Chrome / 88.0.4324.150 Safari / 537.36 Edg / 88.0.705.63")
}
response = requests.get (url, headers = request_headers)
response.raise_for_status ()
soup = BeautifulSoup (response.text, "html.parser")
headers = ["Year", "Month", "Day", "Hour", "Minute", "Second", "T", "Height"]

with open ("station-56003.csv", "w") as f:
    writer = csv.writer (f, lineterminator = "\ n")
    writer.writerow (headers)

    for line in soup.select_one ("# data"). text.split ("\ n"):
        if re.fullmatch (r "[\ d.] {30}", line) and len (line.split ()) == len (headers):
            writer.writerow (line.split ())
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider checking checksum of csv file. If it has changed it means that there are new data.

Comment: if to pull data for 6 hours, is there a way to use beautifulsoup?

Comment: Just write function that sends request in 6 hour interval and saves it to file, then compare chceksum of new on with previous one.